# key typechecking in mypy Dict type

Tags: python, typechecking, mypy

I recently started using mypy. 
Is there a way I can typecheck on Dic keys in mypy.

For ex).

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple, Optional 
import sys


adj_list: Dict[int,List[int]] = {} 

if "x" not in adj_list.keys():
    print('Not found')
```

The above code doesn't show any mypy warnings. In the following code I'm comparing a string object with Dictionary key which can only hold a int key. Is there a way mypy can warn about this invalid comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- use the `--strict-equality` flag. If you enable this flag, mypy will produce the following error:

```py
test.py:8: error: Non-overlapping container check (element type: "str", container item type: "int")
```

You can find more information about this flag near the bottom of the [Miscellaneous strictness options section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#miscellaneous-strictness-flags) in the mypy docs about command line flags it supports.

There are many more strictness flags you can enable, if you prefer more stricter typechecking -- using the `--strict` flag will enable most of them. (Though not the `--strict-equality` flag, which must be configured separately.